# making composition relationship between models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oop, relationship, composition

i have a background about OOP

I know these

```
//association by

has_many
belongs_to

//aggregation by

composed_of

//Inheritance => STI & MTI
```

how i can implement a composition relationship  ?

can i make it like

```
has_many, dependency: :destroy
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dependent: :destroy`, as shown below:

```
 has_many model_name, dependent: :destroy
```

Here is an example:

```
class Author
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
end
```

An `Author` can have many `Posts`. When the Author is destroyed all of its child posts are also destroyed.

Comment: is it the best way to do ?

Comment: Yes, that is usually the way you would do it with Rails